Why does apt list show arm64 packages on my amd64 machine?
I would like to get an explanation as to why apt list command shows two arm64 packages on my amd64 machine/system - Linux Mint 22 (Ubuntu Noble based). And once explained, let's discuss if I can do something about it.

Please note, that I remove the following message, along with possibly other unimportant strings from the below listings for shortness.

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.


Running these commands as a user or root, or changing the way I specify grep filter, does not have any effect on the result, which is always the same = two arm64 Sublime packages show up on my amd64 machine.
Before I start, let me mention the manual pages first: 1) GNU grep; 2) POSIX grep.
# apt list | grep -v 'amd64\|all\|i386'  # I ran this as root

sublime-merge/apt/stable 2102 arm64
sublime-text/apt/stable 4189 arm64

$ apt list | grep 'arm64$'  # I ran this as an ordinary user

sublime-merge/apt/stable 2102 arm64
sublime-text/apt/stable 4189 arm64

Now, let's get some basic info about these packages:
$ apt list sublime-text sublime-merge

sublime-merge/wilma,apt/stable 2102 amd64
sublime-merge/apt/stable 2102 arm64
sublime-text/apt/stable,now 4189 amd64 [installed]
sublime-text/apt/stable 4189 arm64

^^ Why the heck are those two arm64 architecture packages showing up? It's been a long time since I have edited most of my /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.{list,sources} to explicitly contain the architecture, and I thought it would enforce it, no?
$ apt-cache policy sublime-text sublime-merge

sublime-text:
  Installed: 4189
  Candidate: 4189
  Version table:
 *** 4189 500
        500 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     4186 500
        500 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ Packages
     4180 500
        500 http://packages.linuxmint.com wilma/import amd64 Packages
        500 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ Packages
...

sublime-merge:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2102
  Version table:
     2102 500
        500 http://packages.linuxmint.com wilma/import amd64 Packages
        500 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ Packages
     2096 500
        500 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ Packages
     2091 500
        500 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ Packages
...

I have explicitly set, where applicable, the amd64 architecture like so:
deb [arch=amd64 ...

and the sublime-text sources list file is not an exception from this rule of mine:
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.list

deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/sublimehq-archive.gpg] https://download.sublimetext.com/ apt/stable/

So, now I am not sure what this arch=amd64 clause in there is actually doing, if not preventing loading/downloading only this particular architecture from such repository?
Would anyone care to clarify, please? And if you know how to prevent this from happening, I would appreciate it. Thank you.

For completness, let me specify my primary and other architectures I have added to my OS:
$ dpkg --print-architecture
amd64

$ dpkg --print-foreign-architectures
i386

Cheers.

This will be a comments section:
1st request came from Stephen Kitt, thank you.
$ apt policy sublime-{text,merge}:arm64

sublime-text:arm64:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4189
  Version table:
     4189 500
        500 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ Packages
     4186 500
        500 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ Packages
     4180 500
        500 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ Packages
...

sublime-merge:arm64:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2102
  Version table:
     2102 500
        500 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ Packages
     2096 500
        500 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ Packages
     2091 500
        500 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ Packages
...


Filtering architectures using arch statements in repository configurations only selects downloaded Packages files; as far as I can tell it doesn’t affect later processing of repository catalogs. The Sublime Text repositories provide merged Packages files with information on their packages on all the architectures they support; if you look at the contents of /var/lib/apt/lists/download.sublimetext.com_apt_stable_Packages you’ll see amd64 and arm64 packages. As a result, the arm64 packages are available in the local catalog.
The only way I know of to fix this is for Sublime Text to publish separate, per-architecture Packages files.

Adding a bit to this: Using a centralized Packages file that covers all architectures significantly simplifies creation and management of the repository and has next to no downsides as long as the total number of packages (counting all architectures) is not too high, so it’s relatively common among repositories whose owners don’t want to deal with the often unnecessarily complex ‘standard’ tooling for managing APT repositories.
